# An error occurred while running subprocess cordova. cordova.cmd platform add android exited with exit code 1

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I ran the following command in my ionic project

```
ionic cordova platform add android
```

and I got the error

```
> cordova.cmd platform add android
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@^9.0.0
Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@^9.0.0
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
CordovaError: Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 4294963248 Error output:
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\shafi\Desktop\newwest\testmakingAPK\myapp\node_modules\.bin\ng.cmd
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\shafi\Desktop\newwest\testmakingAPK\myapp\node_modules\.bin\ng.cmd'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\shafi\Desktop\newwest\testmakingAPK\myapp\node_modules\.bin\ng.cmd'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\shafi\\Desktop\\newwest\\testmakingAPK\\myapp\\node_modules\\.bin\\ng.cmd'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\shafi\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-07-01T05_45_13_193Z-debug.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova.cmd platform add android exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

I tried the solutions like removing and adding cordova, and other solutions given in stackoverflow, neither of them worked

Who can help me solve this issue?
Thank you)

Comment: I followed this tutorial to build an APK https://wakeupcoders.medium.com/how-to-make-a-apk-file-from-ionic-project-9be865f19846

Comment: looks like permission issue. run your cmd as administrator.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib thanks for the reply, I just did and i still get the same error ((

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
ionic cordova prepare android
```

If you don't want to build the project, use the flag --no-build

```
ionic cordova prepare android --no-build
```

More information about "ionic cordova prepare" [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/cordova-prepare)

Answer (score 0):

as per my case, I did delete the android folder, also if you did try to create your project with some other frameworks like capacitor, delete them either and retry to rerun again